# How does memory allocation of non-homogeneous array work?

Tags: c

Using a `union`, we can certainly have an array containing elements of different data types.

e.g.

```
struct elements { 
    int s;
    union {
        int ival;
        float fval;
        char *pval;
    } element;
};
struct darray {
    struct elements items[100];
};
```

Now, we can declare an array which can contain elements of different data types:

```
struct darray a;
```

What is troubling me: Only a single member of a union can exist at a single time, but we have already got an array containing 100 elements. These elements aren't initialized, but shouldn't memory be allocated here?

How does memory allocation works in such arrays?

Comment: You say: "we can certainly have an array containing elements of different types".  That is incorrect; you can only have arrays of a homogeneous type. You only show an array of a homogeneous type — the type is `struct elements`, which is a type that contains an `int` and a `union` of three different types, but `struct elements` is always the same size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look on the following piece of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef union __attribute__((__packed__)) {
    int   ival;
    int   fval;
    char* pval;
} element;

typedef struct __attribute__((__packed__)) { 
    int     s;
    element e;
} elements;

typedef struct __attribute__((__packed__)) {
    elements items[100];
} darray;

int main()
{
    darray d = {0};
    printf("size of element: %lu.\n", sizeof(element));
    printf("size of elements: %lu.\n", sizeof(elements));
    printf("size of darray: %lu.\n", sizeof(darray));
    return 0;
}
// The output is:
//  size of element: 8
//  size of elements: 12
//  size of elements: 1200
```

Now let's explain what has just happened:

1. I'm using 64-bit machine so pointers are of size 8.
2. We used `__attribute__((__packed__))` in order to force the compiler not padding our structs with extra bytes of memory. It's like telling him, use the minimum amount of memory you need to build a struct which contains the following members.
3. Notice that although it's unknown what `element` is carrying right now, it already has size in **compile time**. The size of element is 8, Why? union size is fixed by its larger member (here we have `int`, which is 4, `float` which is 4, and `char*` which is 8 [64-bit machine again...]).
4. Now that we know that union has a fixed size, creating array of 100 members, will require memory of `100 * sizeof(elements) = 100 * (sizeof(int) + sizeof(element)) = 100 * (4 + 8) = 1200` bytes.

Answer (score 1):

The array is homogeneous, but it's contents includes a union which may represent different types using the same underlying memory.

Each element is its own object with its own members s and element.

You are free to assign different types to different elements:

```
enum
{
    INT , 
    FLOAT , 
    STRING ,
} ;

struct darray a;
a.items[0].s = INT;
a.items[0].element.ival = 12345;
a.items[1].s = FLOAT;
a.items[1].element.fval = 4.56F;
a.items[2].s = STRING;
a.items[2].element.pval = "string literal";

printf( "%d %f %s\n" , a.items[0].element.ival , 
                       a.items[1].element.fval , 
                       a.items[2].element.pval );
```

Instead of wrapping the type struct elements into type struct darray, you could also simply define an array of type struct elements:

```
struct elements a[100];
```

Comment: Okay. As you showed, I can assign different types to different elements, but how does `Memory Allocation` work?